# Loading the file in java code using WEKA's library throws java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: jboss, wildfly, weka, file-conversion

I use a Wildfly 10 and a WEKA 3.8 in my Java EE project. I'm trying to load a CSV file in java code for the WEKA by means of the WEKA's library (based on [THIS](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code) article, chapter `3.5.5 and newer`):

```
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;

....

DataSource source=new DataSource(pathFile.toString());

...
```

Unfortunately, the above code throws this exception:

> Problem with 'weka.filters.UnsupervisedFilter': java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader

**Do you have any idea what can I do to fix this issue?** Is it a Wildfly bug or a WEKA's library bug?

Full stacktrace:

```
10:33:04,226 INFO  [stdout] (default task-29) Problem with 'weka.filters.UnsupervisedFilter': java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader

10:33:04,227 INFO  [stdout] (default task-29) Problem with 'weka.filters.UnsupervisedFilter': java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader

10:33:04,228 INFO  [stdout] (default task-29) Problem with 'weka.classifiers.IterativeClassifier': java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader

10:33:04,228 INFO  [stdout] (default task-29) Problem with 'weka.classifiers.IterativeClassifier': java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader

10:33:04,228 INFO  [stdout] (default task-29) Problem with 'weka.experiment.Tester': java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader

// OTHER EXCETIONS [Problem with 'weka.*': java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader]

10:33:04,427 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-29) #{dataAnalysisController.load()}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: javax.faces.FacesException: #{dataAnalysisController.load()}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.initialize(ConverterUtils.java:772)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.<clinit>(ConverterUtils.java:728)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.<init>(ConverterUtils.java:126)
    at com.system.analysis.LearningMachine.load(LearningMachine.java:34)
    at com.system.analysis.DataMining.saveToFileMethod1(DataMining.java:284)
    at com.system.analysis.DataMining.getMethod1(DataMining.java:113)
    at com.system.analysis.DataTableWectorsMethod1Class.load(DataTableWectorsMethod1Class.java:45)
    at com.system.controller.DataAnalysisController.load(DataAnalysisController.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:415)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1758)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1833)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1696)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:863)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:666)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:637)
    at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.determineClasses(GenericObjectEditor.java:242)
    at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.<clinit>(GenericObjectEditor.java:257)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: My guess is WEKA is expecting a `URLClassLoader` which isn't what WildFly uses. I'd say it's a bug in WEKA.

Comment: I've reported this issue to the WEKA. I also noticed that the problem applies to the CSV files. If I try load the ARFF files, everything work. Apart from that, the part of the WEKA's library isn't work due to unexpected `URLClassLoader`.